# Precision loss when converting from int64 and uint64 C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following code fragment in C++:

```
int64_t a = VALUE;

uint64_t b = a;

int64_t c = b;
```

Is there a VALUE for which `a != c`?

Comment: Check your self [from min to max](https://onlinegdb.com/rJNFK4b88)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a VALUE for which `a != c`?

### Pre C++20

Yes, theoretically any value less than `0` will cause you an issue.  With a value less than `0`, `b` will get a value greater than `std::numeric_limits<int64>::max()` and that means that there will be an implementation defined conversion from `b` to `c`.

For standard desktop machines where all integers are two's complement, then `a` will equal `c`.  For a machine where signed and unsigned integers have different complement's, `a` may/will not equal `c`.

### C++20

No, all integer types are two's complement so the value will be preserved.